# Mule Groovy string replace payload contains question marks

Tags: groovy, utf-8, mule, anypoint-studio

```
String header = "EXL=TST+​[Placeholder1]​+[Placeholder2]+[Placeholder3]​:[Placeholder2]​"

header = header.replaceAll("\\[Placeholder1\\]", escapeEdi((String)${propertyVal1}))
header = header.replaceAll("\\[Placeholder2\\]", escapeEdi((String)${propertyVal2}))
header = header.replaceAll("\\[Placeholder3\\]", escapeEdi((String)${propertyVal3}))

println(header)

String escapeEdi(String target){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : target.toCharArray()){
        switch(c){
            case '+':
            case ':':
            case '\'':
            case '?':
                result.append("?");
            default:
                result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

With the above sample code, I'm getting the payload result with a lot of question marks within it:

Example payload:

```
EXL=TST+​1+?1234?+1234+123?:123?+?1-1-170101?++?TEST?'
```

Even removing the escapeEdi function nets the exact same result.  I'm not even sure if the escape edi is needed, and frankly none of the values passed have any such characters, purely alphanumeric.

Because of the ?, it's causing the message to be sent with a UTF-8-BOM, and their end is just not designed to handle it, which means it must be cleared and removed on my end.  How can I get rid of all these ?

A simple replaceAll with an empty string didn't work.
Trying to escapeEdi() at the end of the result didn't do anything either, and I have a very similar script to this which works just fine, no silly character included.  What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Even just trying to print the string with placeholders on its own seems to be getting me these "?" is there a specific character that might be causing this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the funny thing )

the following code

```
String header = "EXL=TST+​[Placeholder1]​+xxx"
header = header.replaceAll("\\[Placeholder1\\]", "val1")
println header
```

produces

```
EXL=TST+?val1?+xxx
```

and finally i found that there is a strange spaces before and after `[]` in your source string with uni-code value (8203)

and it is [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)

see on the screenshot in green:

[image]

Comment: I found out the hard way just before reading this, ended up copying the entire result with ?s, replacing ?s with an empty string, and then plugging them back in to get it to work.  Really well done and smartly spotted - is that Notepad++?  and how did you get them to show to figure it out?

Comment: yes, it's notepad++ screen/ but i detected symbol in "Far Manager editor". Usually when the question about real characters & bytes - that's the best for me =)